# Does array contain?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

I have the following array in JS

```
 var wordselection = [
{ 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },

];   

function randomword(){
var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word
document.getElementById("wordinput").innerHTML=chosen;
}
```

I currently have the randomword function which generates a random "word" from the array and puts it in a div (e.g pomme, chat)

I need to create another function which checks what the random word actually is in the div and then works out if the gender of that word in the array is 'm' or 'f'.

For example if the random word is generated as 'Poisson', I need a function which realises 'poisson' was generated and look in the array to see that it is gender 'f'

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plain JS solution that does what you want:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">Chat</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var wordselection = [
{ 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m" },
{ "word": "Banane", "gender": "f"},
{ "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m" },
{ "word": "Chat", "gender": "f" },
{ "word": "Chien", "gender": "m" },
{ "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f" }

];   

var word = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;

var item = wordselection.filter(function(el){
  return el.word == word
})[0];

console.log(item && item.gender);
```

It logs undefined if the word in the div is not from the list.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AlOtINE/1/edit

**EDIT:** If you need to check many such words, you can get better performance by storing them in a map (also known as Object in JavaScript):

```
var wordselection = {
  'Pomme' : 'm',
  'Banane' : 'f',
  'Ananas' : 'm',
  'Chat' : 'f',
  'Chien' : 'm',
  'Poisson' : 'f'
}
```

Then the filtering part is as simple as:

```
console.log(wordselection[word]); // gender or undefined
```

If you get the wordselection from an external source but still want to convert it to the above format you can use this snippet:

```
var optimizedwordselection;
for (var i=0; i<wordselection.length; i++) {
  optimizedwordselection[wordselection.word] = wordselection.gender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full code structure or actual implementation. However, I would do it either of the 2 ways. There might be many other ways to achieve the solution.

1. Copy the HTML of the DIV element using http://api.jquery.com/html/ 
   in a variable. The HTML will be stored as a string. Search in the
   string and see if the "word" exists. If it does or does not, take
   appropriate action.
2. Create a temporary Array. Store the key value pairs in that Array. E.g. {"Poisson","F"}. Later when you want to find whether the "word" exists, just search in the Array whether they key exists or not. If KEY exists, then you can always check its value which will be gender.

```
var holder = new Array();

function randomword(){
    var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word

    if( checkPost(chosen) ){
        document.getElementById("wordinput").innerHTML=chosen;
        holder['chosen'] = gender_variable;
    }
}

function checkPost(word){
    if( holder[word] === undefined ) {
        return null;
    }
    return holder[word];
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some code for the second option please?

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow and dont know how to put code in comment. So adding a new answer. Please check.

Comment: To put code in comment you can surround it with this character: `. Also, editing your answer instead of adding a new one is almost always the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want using JQuery:

JavaScript code:

```
 var wordselection = [
{ 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },

];  


     $.each( wordselection, function(key, value) {

         if ( value.word == $('#result').html() )
         {
             alert(value.gender);
         }
     })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GWUxc/

Or using your random function:

```
 var wordselection = [
{ 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },

];  

function randomword(){
    var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word
document.getElementById("wordinput").innerHTML=chosen;
}

     randomword()
     $.each( wordselection, function(key, value) {

         if ( value.word == $('#wordinput').html() )
         {
             alert(value.gender);
         }
     })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GWUxc/1/

Anyway, I like more the solution using `filter` approach: [Does array contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266810/does-array-contain/19267042#19267092)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use any other libraries?  If I were you I'd use lo dash, it can handle this kind of thing for you without you having to iterate over the collection yourself.  For example, all you'd need to do is:

```
var wordselection = [
    { 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
    { "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
    { "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
    { "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
    { "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
    { "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },
];

var gender = _.find(wordSelection, { 'word': "Banane" }).gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through your array of JSON objects:

```
var wordselection = [
  { 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
  { "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
  { "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
  { "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
  { "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
  { "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },
]; 

var selectedWord = "Chien";
var selectedWordGender;
for(var i = 0; i < wordselection.length; i++) {
  if(wordselection[i].word === selectedWord)
  {
      selectedWordGender = wordselection[i].gender;
  }
}     

console.log(selectedWordGender);
```

Comment: I didn't know `filter` existed. I think @Tibos has the best answer